# Navigation bar is removed when pushing a viewcontroller from another storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have many storyboards in my project to have modules with specific functionalities. In one of my storyboard, I have a navigation controller, which push the initial view controller of another storyboard. When I push it, the navigation bar is removed and there is no way to get this specific bar back. When I put another navigation controller in my new  storyboard, the navigation bar is resetted with an ugly transition (it comes from the right and replace the older one).

This is how I push my new storyboard's view controller :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:aStoryboardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *SideBarInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[GDFromRightCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:aSegueIdentifier source:aSource destination:SideBarInitialViewController];
[segue perform];
```

I perform a custom segue as well to get rid of the basic animation (the view coming from below) :

```
UIView *sourceView = [self.sourceViewController view];
UIView *destinationView = [self.destinationViewController view];

CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

destinationView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window insertSubview:destinationView aboveSubview:sourceView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    destinationView.frame = CGRectOffset(destinationView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0);
    sourceView.frame = CGRectOffset(sourceView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:false completion:nil];
}];
```

Is there a way to push the new storyboard without animate the navigation bar, or even better, to have the older navigation controller in my new storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

In your source storyboard drag a new **UIViewController** and then drag a ** Modal segue** to this new **UIViewController** from your **source** ViewController. Click on this segue and then in the attributes Inspector add a Identifier of segue (let say "**newSegue**") Identifier must be unique. Also set segue type to "**Custom** " and write "**newSegue**" in **Segue Class**

Now add a catagory on **UIStoryBoardSegue** with name **newSegue** and in the .m file write these two methods.

```
- (id) initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                   source:(UIViewController *)source
              destination:(UIViewController *)destination
{
    return [super initWithIdentifier:identifier
                              source:source
                         destination:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourDestinationStoryBoardName" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController ]];
}

- (void)perform
{

    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;

   [source presentViewController:self.destinationViewController
                                          animated:YES
                                        completion:Nil];

}
```

Now in your source ViewController when you want to presenth new View Controller write this line

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"newSegue" sender:nil];
```

Must Remember to replace "YourDestinationStoryBoardName" with your actual destination StoryBoard name in the above function.

Try this Hope this will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This work pretty fine, but is there a way to not get it as a stack (with the "back" button) ? I mean by that, I wanted the exact ancient navigation controller

Comment: Yeah for that purpose you can use Modal Segue i am editing the answer so you can look again in that.Use this line [source presentViewController:self.destinationViewController
                                          animated:YES
                                        completion:Nil];

Comment: Use this line [source presentViewController:self.destinationViewController
                                          animated:YES
                                        completion:Nil];
in Perform method

Comment: When presenting a viewcontroller, the navigation controller is erased ! Is it really a modal segue ?

Comment: Yup when you present ViewController Modally then navigation Controller is erased, so if you want to keep the navigation Controller then you should use Push Segue.

Comment: That's what i said before, is there a way to keep the navigation bar as it was in the last view ? with no button back ? Push is deprecated as well now

Comment: Push is not depreciated and also You cannot remove back button as its an Default IOS behavior .

Comment: You can use this hack , you can add custom back button with no Title.
**self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:nil
           action:nil];**